# Do INLINE pragmas cause inlining even if optimizations are disabled?

Tags: haskell, ghc, inlining

[GHC docs on INLINE pragmas](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/pragmas.html#inline-and-noinline-pragmas):

> GHC (with -O, as always) tries to inline (or “unfold”) functions/values that are “small enough,” [...]
>
> The major effect of an INLINE pragma is to declare a function’s “cost” to be very low. The normal unfolding machinery will then be very keen to inline it. [...]

I take this to mean that without optimizations enabled, even `{-# INLINE ... #-}` functions / values will not be inlined, since the "normal unfolding machinery" will not even be run to notice the function's cost has been reduced.

Is that correct?

Comment: While I have no idea, you could try to experiment a bit with `-ddump-simpl` and see what kind of Core code is being generated in both cases. You should be able to observe whether something gets inlined or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `-O0` still invokes a single pass of the "simplifier", which is the optimization pass responsible for, among other things, inlining.

You can't prevent the simplifier from being called, but you can set the number of simplifier iterations to zero, which should cause it to bail out before doing anything:

```
ghc -O0 -fmax-simplifier-iterations=0 -ddump-simpl
```

For your `handleThing` example, this prevents the inlining you've observed.

The inlining that occurs with `-O0` is limited to what can be accomplished by inlining fully saturated calls with no eta expansion/reduction.  This means that your example:

```
handleThing = print
{-# INLINE handleThing #-}
main = mapM_ handleThing [1..10]
```

will inline, but the variation:

```
handleThing x = print x
{-# INLINE handleThing #-}
main = mapM_ handleThing [1..10]
```

won't, since the call to `handleThing` in `main` is no longer fully saturated.

On the other hand, this will inline both `number` and `handleThing`:

```
number = 10
{-# INLINE number #-}
handleThing x = print x >> print x
{-# INLINE handleThing #-}
main = handleThing number
```

into `main`, resulting in:

```
x = 10
main = >> $fMonadIO (print $fShowInteger x) (print $fShowInteger x)
```

Here, "inlining" `number` involves the de-optimization of giving it an extra name and using that.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: `INLINE` pragmas can cause inlining, even with optimizations off.

I used the following `Main.hs` as a test case:

```
module Main where

handleThing :: Integer -> IO ()
handleThing = print
-- {-# INLINE handleThing #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mapM_ handleThing [1..10]
```

`ghc -ddump-simpl` with the pragma removed contains this:

```
main :: IO ()
[GblId]
main
  = mapM_
      @[]
      @IO
      @Integer
      @()
      Data.Foldable.$fFoldable[]
      GHC.Base.$fMonadIO
      handleThing
      (enumFromTo @Integer GHC.Enum.$fEnumInteger 1 10)
```

`ghc -ddump-simpl Main.hs` with the pragma has this instead:

```
main :: IO ()
[GblId]
main
  = mapM_
      @[]
      @IO
      @Integer
      @()
      Data.Foldable.$fFoldable[]
      GHC.Base.$fMonadIO
      (print @Integer GHC.Show.$fShowInteger)
      (enumFromTo @Integer GHC.Enum.$fEnumInteger 1 10)
```

`handleThing` has been replaced by `(print @Integer GHC.Show.$fShowInteger)`. Obviously not a dramatic change, but interesting that the inliner runs at all.

In both cases, `ghc --show-iface Main.hi` did not contain an unfolding, so (AIUI) `handleThing` would not be available for cross-module inlining.